# Issues streaming video from one raspberry pi to another which are connected using ethernet cables via python opencv and picamera2

Tags: python, opencv, sockets, video-streaming, ethernet

Hi I've been having issues where I have a set up where I have three raspberry pis two with cameras on them and one that I'm looking to host and display the streamed outputs of the pis via tkinter.

I'm having trouble trying to pipe the stream from one of the client pis with the cameras on them to the "mother" pi with the GUI on it. I have tried following the steps which are in the documentation for picamera2 to allow for sending video via ethernet using the "socket" module, however I'm either sending it incorrectly or not reading the correct thing on the mother pi as opencv fails each time I try.

The code on the camera pi looks like this:

```
import socket
import time

from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder
from picamera2.outputs import FileOutput

# Local imports
from establish_connection import EstablishConnection

picam2 = Picamera2()
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration({"size": (1280, 720)})
picam2.configure(video_config)
encoder = H264Encoder(1000000)

connection = EstablishConnection()

while True:
    connection.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    picam2.encoder = encoder
    stream = connection.sock.makefile("wb")
    picam2.encoder.output = FileOutput(stream)
    picam2.start_encoder()
    picam2.start()
    time.sleep(20)
    picam2.stop()
    picam2.stop_encoder()
```

with the establish connection class looking like this:

```
import socket
import time

# Global Variables
global MOTHER_IP
MOTHER_IP = '169.254.83.151'

global MOTHER_SOCKET
MOTHER_SOCKET = 8080

class EstablishConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = MOTHER_IP
        self.port = MOTHER_SOCKET

        print('Attempting to connect to EDB-Mother...')
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        while True: 
            try:
                self.sock.connect((MOTHER_IP, MOTHER_SOCKET))  # IP address of second Pi and port number
                print('Connected to EDB-Mother.')
                self.is_valid = True
                return

            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                self.is_valid = False
```

And finally the code on the receiving side of things looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
import socket
import numpy as np
import time

# Local modules
from video_stream import VideoStream

class DisplayVideoStream:
    def __init__(self, host, port, width, height):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.socket = None
        self.connection = None
        self.frame = None
        self.image = None
        self.root = None
        self.label = None
        self.is_running = False

    def start(self):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.socket.listen(1)
        print(f"Listening on {self.host}:{self.port}")
        self.connection, address = self.socket.accept()
        print(f"Connected to {address}")

        # Establish video stream link
        self.camera_stream = VideoStream(address[0], self.port)

        # Create the GUI window
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("1280x720")
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root)
        self.label.pack()

        self.is_running = True
        self.update_frame()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        if self.socket: self.socket.close()
        if self.connection: self.connection.close()

    def update_frame(self):
        if not self.is_running: return

        # Get an image from the stream
        self.image = self.camera_stream.get_frame()

        # Update the label with the new image
        self.label.configure(image=self.image)

        # Schedule the next update
        self.root.after(1, self.update_frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Change these parameters to match your setup
    host = '169.254.83.151'
    port = 8080
    width = 1280
    height = 720

    stream = DisplayVideoStream(host, port, width, height)
    stream.start()
```

with VideoStream() looking like this,

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class VideoStream:
    def __init__(self, ip_address, port):

        self.video_source = f'tcp://{ip_address}:{port}/'
        
        # Open the video stream
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_source)

        # Check if capture is open
        if not self.cap.isOpened(): print("Unable to open video stream")
        else: print("Stream opened")

    def get_frame(self):
        # Read a frame from the video stream
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()

        if ret:
            # Convert the frame from OpenCV BGR format to Pillow RGB format
            image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            # Resize the image to fit the canvas
            image = image.resize((320, 240))

            # Convert the image to a Tkinter PhotoImage
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)

            return photo
```

I have tried this and am expecting a GUI to pop up with the stream from the camera from the other pi updating within it however the error that I'm getting is this:

```
Listening on 169.254.83.151:8080
Connected to ('169.254.133.19', 39982)
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not get/set settings from/on resource.
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (914) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ERROR:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (140) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): udp://169.254.133.19:8080/ in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

I so I know that there is either something wrong with the `self.video_souce` found in VideoStream and that url is bad, or on the camera-pi side of things I'm just sending it the wrong way.